# AWS Lambda + custom authorizer + JWT + blacklisted token

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jwt, lambda-authorizer

I create serverless app using custom authorizer and JWT (`jsonwebtoken`).

I want to add blacklisted tokens.

How do it best? Where store them? How to check them in authorizer?

I made a research in google but I didn't find good solution.

Comment: What do you mean by `custom authorizer`? You want to implement your own authentication logic? If you are open to using `AWS Cognito` as authorizer, I can help you

Comment: @SagarCh Yes, I implemented my authentication logic. Now I am not going to use Cognito, but if I decide, I will ask you for help.

Comment: `API Gateway` supports `custom authorizer` through lambda. So to authenticate requests to your original lambda, you need write another lambda with authorizer for authentication

Comment: Yes, I know. I have problem with adding blacklisted tokens. I wonder how to do it best - without requesting database for checking blacklist in all request.

Comment: Ideally, there should not be any `blacklist` tokens at all (and also, tokens should be short lived). If you want to disable access to certain client, you should disable the client itself( meaning, he should not be able to generate new token from ClientId/ClientSecret), which will disable corresponding tokens.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, for secure production purposes JWT tokens should not be long-lived. The client using the JWT needs to "refresh" the tokens with the authentication back-end periodically, e.g. every 5 minutes. Thus, if you "block" a user on your authentication back-end, the token will not refresh and will lose access.

This is just how JWT was designed. Read more about how this process should work here: https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/

However, if you don't care about security or you want to force a blacklist on JWTs, you can use any database mechanism to store the blacklisted tokens. My recommendation is something like DynamoDB which is pretty cheap.

Here's a node.js example of how to read/write data from a DynamoDB table: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-table-read-write.html